# Can't get xdebug to send back information: PhpStorm+xdebug+ec2-linux

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, phpstorm, xdebug

So according to my php.ini and PhpStorm (validate debugger configuration on web server) xdebug is perfectly installed and configured and PhpStorm is able to receive and send info to xdebug on the remote server.

YET, when I add break points and clearly reached those break points, I don't get any debugger info like variables and their contents. I have no idea what I'm still missing but here is my `phpinfo()` screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT**
I also have installed in chrome browser the extension the xdebug helper.  which is enabled.  Here is my xdebug log:

```
    Log opened at 2017-06-27 04:02:49
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to <my address>:9000.
W: Creating socket for '<my address>:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-06-27 04:02:49

Log opened at 2017-06-27 04:04:58
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to <my address>:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-06-27 04:04:59

Log opened at 2017-06-27 04:05:22
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to <my address>:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-06-27 04:05:22

Log opened at 2017-06-27 04:05:58
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to <my address>:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-06-27 04:05:58

Log opened at 2017-06-27 04:06:05
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to <my address>:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-06-27 04:06:05
```

**EDIT**
Here is the javascript for the phpstorm bookmark that I use to activate a xdebug session:

```
javascript:(/** @version 0.5.2 */function() {document.cookie='XDEBUG_SESSION='+'PHPSTORM'+';path=/;';})()
```

**EDIT**

Here is screenshot of my resource monitor on windows that indeed shows phpstorm.exe is listening on port 9000 and that port is open for communication:

[image]

Comment: How do you start debug session? Can you see that it's been started in PhpStorm?

Comment: Like the phpstorm tutorial says by going to run->debug.  I then see chrome light up and when I go to it I can see the "Jetbrains IDE support" is debugging this browser - notification up top in chrome webpage which means phpstorm is able to communicate with chrome(atleast) for xdebug related info.

Comment: Usually I don't use run->debug command. When extension is enabled you can just open the page you need and if breakpoint is set while this page rendering your script will top there. Be sure that remote_debug is enabled. Also you have to turn on listening remote connection button in the PHPStorm

Comment: @Dave2345 Message about Jetbrains IDE support means you run Javascript debug and not PHP debug - open Run > Edit configurations and check the list of configurations by yourself, you will see that type of configuration that you run is Javascript Debug. Please follow this guide: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm , it does not require any Run/Debug configurations, just enable listening for Xdebug and then use Xdebug browser extension in browser at the page you need.

Comment: @VladLuchansky ok i followed that tutorial exactly and removed jetbrains chrome ext and the configuration for it in phpstorm and still i get no incoming connections from xdebug.

Comment: @Dave2345 this is local server, correct? Did you use Xdebug browser extension? Did you set it to debug? When you enable PhpStorm to listen for incoming connections, can you confirm with "netstat" that it listens on port 9000?

Comment: @VladLuchansky no this is for remote debugging.  Xdebug/PHP are on a remote server and I my phpstorm is on my local machine which I am trying to get xdebug to communicate with.  So basically I'm setting break points etc on my local machine files(which I have mapped to remote host already) and trying to debug remotely.  https://xdebug.org/docs/remote jump to section on remote debugging.  And yes I used xdebug browser extension(the one with the bug icon that lights up green when enabled).  I have to try netstat, ill get back to you on that.

Comment: @VladLuchansky ok i just checked on my local machine if port 9000 is open and being listened to which it is by phpstorm.exe.  And it says the firewall allows, not restricted - which means port is open and open for communication.

Comment: @Dave2345 So if you enable PhpStorm to listen for incoming connections and then do "telnet 127.0.0.1 9000", does it connect?

Comment: @VladLuchansky says connection failed.

Comment: @VladLuchansky sorry no it just goes to blank cmd screen.

Comment: @Dave2345 means that we are connecting fine. Did you create a deployment configuration for a local web server? Did you set the mappings in Mappings tab? They cannot be empty.

Comment: @vlad like I said earlier I am doing remote debugging.  Xdebug and website are on remote server.  And yes I set my path mapping s.  So to clarify there is. NO local server.  I use PHPSTORM to connect to remote server and debug remotely.

Comment: @Dave2345 Then why Xdebug remote host is 127.0.0.1? It should be the address of the machine where your PhpStorm is running.

Comment: @VladLuchansky ya that picture is outdated...i changed it to my ip of phpstorm machine.  Still i get no xdebug communication.

Comment: @Dave2345 Is there a direct connection between your machine and remote server? Can you reach port 9000 on your local machine from that server?

Comment: @VladLuchansky no my machine is not physically next to the server, it's remote.

Comment: @Dave2345 then how connection would be established then? Did you try to setup the tunnel or is there any direct IP/DNS name option?

Comment: @VladLuchansky what do you mean by tunnel?

Comment: @Dave2345 In order to get the debugger communicate between your machine with PhpStorm and remote server with web server, it is necessary to have the ability to connect from remote server to your machine directly. If this is not possible, a tunnel should be established. Usual case is SSH tunnel or VPN.

Comment: @ so all remote debugging requires and SSH tunnel or VPN is what  your saying?  Because in xdebug's remote debugging tutorial it doesn't mention anything about SSH tunnel or VPN:  https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Xdebug can't connect to IP address `<myaddress>` on port
9000. Which should be the IP address of your Windows machine. It can be
a Windows Firewall (or "Defender") blocking it, or perhaps there is
something else that blocks the connection. A time-out likely points this
more towards the firewall.

Comment: in windows resource monitor it says port 9000 is open and being listened by phpstorm and is open for communication.  I posted an image in my post(towards the bottom).

Comment: You saved my life, haha. Thank you so much!
In my case was on linux.